# PhpStorm IDE support for returned object

Tags: php, annotations, ide

I'm using a dependency injection container, it returns prepared object via a method, so it's something like:

```
echo $container->get('cookie')->getValue('abc');
```

The `get` method return a `cookie` object but PhpStorm IDE (or any other IDE) doesn't support this part, I want it to tell me what methods `cookie` have but after second `->` the IDE doesn't show method list, I know if I save the `get` result in a variable it's possible to notify IDE what type the variable is with a line of annotation, but I searching a solution for exactly what I mentioned above (only 1 line).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get() is function, which can return any object. so the IDE does not know what type of object methods to give. You can use the property PhpDoc @mixin which describes possible methods returns the object. I can not say for all IDE, but [it works in PhpStorm](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/11/phpstorm-7-1-eap-133-51/).

Example:

```
class ... {

/**
 * ...
 * @mixin yourCookieClass
 */
public function get($args) {}
}
```

Comment: I guessed that no way to do achieve what i need, but good point, thanks